# Intervalo de carregamento Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Gostaria de Setar um tempo de carregamento entre cada `load()` para completar o carregamento de cada um.
Para isso precisaria setar um stop ou algo semelhante dentro do meu Loop. 
Isso seria possivel?

```
 for (var v = 0;v <= 10 ;v++ ){
   //Esperar 3 Segundos e carregar proxima linha
   $("#minhaDiv"+v).load("pagina.php?par="+v);
 }
```

Obrigado !

Answer (score 0):

O método `delay()` não funcionaria nesse caso por que ele só atrasa a próxima instrução `Jquery` encadeada.
Algo como:

```
$("#minhaDiv"+v).load("pagina.php?par="+v).delay(3000).toggle("show");
```

Neste caso, você pode utilizar um truque ao invés de um for comum, ficaria algo como:

```
var i = 0;                     //  seta seu indíce pára 0

function myLoop () {           //  vamos criar uma função de loop
   setTimeout(function () {    //  Chama a função a cada 3 segundos
      $("#minhaDiv"+i).load("pagina.php?par="+i); //executa seu load.
      i++;                     //  incrementa o índice
      if (i < 10) {            //  se índice é menor que 10, então continua a o looping
         myLoop();             //  chama a função de looping 
      }                        
   }, 3000)
}

myLoop();
```

Basta você adaptar de acordo com seus requisitos.

Me basei nessa resposta [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop).